# Is that possible generate XSS by actionscript's Sound.load() function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, xss

I found some actionscript code like that:

```
var s:Sound = new Sound(); 
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded); 
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XX_EXTERNAL_URL); 
s.load(req);
```

In which case the attacker can control the `XX_EXTERNAL_URL`, is that vulnerable?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it will just generate a sound conversion error or garbage sound, without any extra impact on SWF player or the system. One needs to have a bug in sound code that's causing a code injection or data corruption to make this attack successful. But, with predefined code of `Sound` object, it's either there or not, so it won't be more vulnerable if you load a Sound from elsewhere.